# PouchDB allows unauthorized users to create admins

Tags: authorization, couchdb, admin, pouchdb

I have a pouchdb (using their own server) installation running. If I do

```
curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/_config/admins/anna -d '"secret"'
```

I get `{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}` as expected.

**BUT**, If I use the *pouchdb-authentication* plugin and run the following in the browser (making sure that I'm logged out), it creates a server admin.

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://127.0.0.1:5984/spacedbs')
var aut = db.signUpAdmin('illegal', 'pass')
```

What is going on?!

Comment: What is the state of your CouchDB server? This is normal out-of-the-box behavior. You need to [end the admin party](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/security.html?highlight=admin%20party#the-admin-party).

Comment: If admin party ends as soon as there is a single server admin, then my server is not in admin party mode.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, when I do this:

```
$ curl -kv -X PUT https://root:****@192.168.1.106:6984/_node/couchdb@127.0.0.1/_config/admins/admin -d '"****"'
```

I'm changing the **global** configuration of CouchDB on my machine by adding an extra `admin` user.

---

I don't quite remember how PouchDB worked, but I think when you use PouchDB like this:

```
const db = new PouchDB('http://127.0.0.1:5984/spacedbs')
let aut = db.signUpAdmin('illegal', 'pass')
```

You are just adding admin to a **single** database NOT to the global CouchDB configuration. A `sample` database can have admins/members users/roles like below:

[image]